# Delphi how to make Tshape change color when new text is entered

Tags: delphi, colors, delphi-2010, shapes

im new to programming and i'm unsure why this wont work:

```
procedure TGIFtest.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  Text : integer;
begin
 if text < 5 then
   shape1.brush.Color := clred
 else
   if text >= 5 then
     shape1.brush.Color := clgreen;
 end;
```

I want the shape to be red when a number entered in the edit is less than 5, and green if a number 5 or higher is entered. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The variable `Text` is not initialized, so you will have a random value.

If you want to have the integer value from the Edit text (string), then you have to get this text and convert it to an integer value.

```
procedure TGIFtest.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  Text : integer;
begin

  Text := StrToInt( Edit1.Text );

  if text < 5 then
    shape1.brush.Color := clred
  else
    if text >= 5 then
      shape1.brush.Color := clgreen;
end;
```

If the Edit text can not converted to an integer, an exception is raised.

To avoid this you can use `StrToIntDef` or `TryStrToInt`